# Optimal algorithm to determine relationship tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

Suppose that you have a list of formulas like the following one:

```
KPI1 = somevalue1 + somevalue2
KPI2 = somevalue1 + somevalue3
KPI3 = KPI1 + somevalue4
KPI4 = KPI2 + KPI3
etc.
```

Which is the optimal algorithm that can be used to obtain a relationship tree for each of the elements referenced in the formulas?

i.e., using the example above:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|    somevalue3    somevalue1    somevalue2    somevalue4    |
|        |             | |            |             |        |
|        --------------- --------------             |        |
|               |               |                   |        |
|              KPI2            KPI1                 |        |
|               |               |                   |        |
|               |               ---------------------        |
|               |                         |                  |
|               |                        KPI3                |
|               |                         |                  |
|               ---------------------------                  |
|                            |                               |
|                           KPI4                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hashmap where a key corresponds to a defined name (e.g. "KPI3"), and the corresponding value is a list of names/values on which that name depends (e.g. ["KPI1", somevalue4]).

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, where we can use the native `Map` constructor. Once the map is populated with all the dependencies, a recursive function can for example print the tree:

```js
function printTree(map, name, indent="") {
  console.log(indent + name);
  let children = map.get(name);
  if (children !== undefined) {
    for (let childName of children) {
      printTree(map, childName, indent+"  ");
    }
  }
}

let map = new Map();
map.set("KPI1", ["value1", "value2"]);
map.set("KPI2", ["value1", "value3"]);
map.set("KPI3", ["KPI1", "value4"]);
map.set("KPI4", ["KPI2", "KPI3"]);

printTree(map, "KPI4");
```

In Python you would use a dictionary:

```py
def print_tree(d, name, indent=""):
  print(indent + name)
  children = d.get(name, None)
  if children is not None:
    for childName in children:
      print_tree(d, childName, indent+"  ")

d = dict()
d["KPI1"] = ["value1", "value2"]
d["KPI2"] = ["value1", "value3"]
d["KPI3"] = ["KPI1", "value4"]
d["KPI4"] = ["KPI2", "KPI3"]

print_tree(d, "KPI4")
```